# Why do I get inconsistent results between Fasttext, Longformer, and Doc2vec?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, doc2vec, fasttext

I am using a Doc2Vec model to calculate cosine similarity between observations in a dataset of website text. I want to be sure that my measure is *roughly* consistent if I instead use Fasttext (trained on my data) or Longformer (pre-trained) [I know they won't be identical]. However, the pairwise cosine similarity measure is **strongly negatively correlated** between Doc2Vec & Longformer or Doc2Vec & Fasttext. The measure is positively correlated between Longformer & Fasttext. Is there a reason why one might expect this? Am I mistakenly doing something in my code that could be causing this?

```
# PREPARE DATA
website_df = pd.read_csv(data_path+'cleaned_docdf_may2023.csv')
website_df[['documents_cleaned','website']]=website_df[['documents_cleaned','website']].astype(str)
website_df['documents_cleaned']=website_df['documents_cleaned'].str.lower()
website_df['documents_cleaned']=website_df['documents_cleaned'].str.strip()

####################### 
# Train Doc2vec model
#######################

# Clean data for model input (trim long docs, lower case, tokenize):
counter = 0
all_docs = []
all_docs_simple = []
for train_doc in website_df.documents_cleaned:
    doc = train_doc[:150000] if len(train_doc) > 150000 else train_doc
    # clean using simple_preprocess for Fasttext model input
    simple_pre = gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(train_doc)
    doc = remove_stopwords(doc)
    doc_tokens =nltk.word_tokenize(doc.lower())
    all_docs.append(doc_tokens)
    all_docs_simple.append(simple_pre)
    if (counter%100) == 0:
        print("{0} .. len: {1}".format(counter,len(doc)))
    counter += 1

# Creating all tagged documents
documents_websites = [TaggedDocument(doc, [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(all_docs)]
documents_simplepre_websites = [TaggedDocument(doc, [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(all_docs_simple)]
print("\t. Run model")
doc2vec_model_websites = Doc2Vec(documents = documents_websites,
                vector_size=700,
                window=7,
                min_count =3)
print("\t. Done")
doc2vec_model_websites.save(data_path + "doc2vec_websites.model")

# Grab document level vectors
vectors_d2v_websites = doc2vec_model_websites.dv.get_normed_vectors()

######################### 
# FASTTEXT MODEL
#########################

# create and save Fasttext input
sent_df_websites=pd.Series(documents_simplepre_websites)
with open(data_path + 'sentences_websites', 'a') as f:
    df_string = sent_df_websites.to_string(header=False, index=False)
    f.write(df_string)

# Skipgram model (use comparable model parameters to doc2vec model) :
ft_model_sg_websites = fasttext.train_unsupervised(input=sent_df_websites, model='skipgram', ws=7, epoch=10, minCount=3)
ft_model_sg_websites.save_model(data_path + "ft_websites_sg.bin")
# cbow model (use comparable model parameters to doc2vec model) :
ft_model_cbow_websites = fasttext.train_unsupervised(input=data_path + 'sentences_websites', model='cbow', ws=7, epoch=10, minCount=3)
ft_model_cbow_websites.save_model(data_path + "ft_websites_cbow.bin")

def generateVector(sentence):
    return ft.get_sentence_vector(sentence)

ft = ft_model_sg_websites
website_df['embeddings_sg'] = website_df['documents_cleaned'].apply(generateVector)
embeddings_sg_website=website_df['embeddings_sg']
ft = ft_model_cbow_websites
website_df['embeddings_cbow'] = website_df['documents_cleaned'].apply(generateVector)
embeddings_cbow_website=website_df['embeddings_sg']

#########################
# LONGFORMER 
#########################

model_name = 'allenai/longformer-base-4096'
tokenizer = LongformerTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = LongformerModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

def get_longformer_embeddings(text):
    encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt", max_length=4096, truncation=True)
    output = model(**encoded_input, output_hidden_states=True)
    embeddings = output.last_hidden_state
    avg_emb = embeddings.mean(dim=1)
    return avg_emb.cpu().detach().numpy()

def get_cosine_sim(a,b):
    value = dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))
    return value

# subset data for speed during pilot
website_subset = website_df[:100]
website_subset['embeddings'] = website_subset['documents_cleaned'].apply(get_longformer_embeddings)

#########################
# EVALUATE CONSISTENCY BETWEEN MODELS
#########################

# create dataframe of random pairwise combinations
rand = np.random.randint(1,100,size=(500,2))
df = pd.DataFrame(rand, columns=['rand1', 'rand2'])
df['sim_lf']=0
df['sim_dv']=0
df['sim_ft_sg']=0
df['sim_ft_cbow']=0

for ind in df.index:
    a_loc = df['rand1'][ind]
    b_loc = df['rand2'][ind]
    a_vec_dv = vectors_d2v_websites[a_loc]
    b_vec_dv = vectors_d2v_websites[b_loc]
    a_vec_ft_sg = embeddings_sg_website[a_loc]
    b_vec_ft_sg = embeddings_sg_website[b_loc]
    a_vec_ft_cbow = embeddings_cbow_website[a_loc]
    b_vec_ft_cbow = embeddings_cbow_website[b_loc]
    a_vec_lf = website_subset['embeddings'][a_loc]
    b_vec_lf = website_subset['embeddings'][b_loc].T
    cos_sim_lf = get_cosine_sim(a_vec_lf, b_vec_lf)
    cos_sim_dv = get_cosine_sim(a_vec_dv, b_vec_dv)
    cos_sim_ft_sg = get_cosine_sim(a_vec_ft_sg,b_vec_ft_sg)
    cos_sim_ft_cbow = get_cosine_sim(a_vec_ft_cbow,b_vec_ft_cbow)
    df['sim_lf'][ind]=cos_sim_lf
    df['sim_dv'][ind]=cos_sim_dv
    df['sim_ft_sg'][ind]=cos_sim_ft_sg
    df['sim_ft_cbow'][ind]=cos_sim_ft_cbow

print('MY WEBSITE DATA SIMILARITY')
print('corr(Longformer, Fasttext (skipgram)) = ',df['sim_lf'].corr(df['sim_ft_sg']))
print('corr(Longformer, Fasttext (cbow)) = ',df['sim_lf'].corr(df['sim_ft_cbow']))
print('corr(Longformer, d2v) = ',df['sim_lf'].corr(df['sim_dv']))
print('corr(Fasttext (skipgram), d2v) = ',df['sim_ft_sg'].corr(df['sim_dv']))
print('corr(Fasttext (cbow), d2v) = ',df['sim_ft_cbow'].corr(df['sim_dv']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Training a model with a full 700 dimensions requires a *lot* of data.

Your Fasttext model, by leaving dimensions unspecified, is accepting the default of 100 dimensions.

It appears you're using a pretrained Longformer model that someone else trained on plentiful data.

So my 1st guess would be that you may not have enough data to train a `Doc2Vec` model of that size. For comparison with 100-dimensional Fasttext models trained on the same amount of text, it'd make more sense to try 100-dimensional `Doc2Vec` as well. (Depending on your amount of text, you might then want to go larger, or smaller, on both.)

Finally: independent from any cross-correlation between different techniques, I'd also wnat to know: which technique is offering doc-to-doc similarity results that look best in either ad hoc or formal evaluations. Knowing the best performer – perhaps uncorrelated with the others! – seems more important than similarity between different methods. (And if, perchance, you've got alternate methods that are equally good at your real goal, but not correlated with each other, it's possible a blend of them would offer a big lift.)